# Python producing two instances of data set

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to programming and this seems like a basic problem but I cannot figure it out. The code below creates a .txt file that gives two instances of the last data set.

Could someone help/ explain why this code produces double of the last dataset?
thanks,

```
import urllib
import re
##NL East stats.
teamstate = ["wsh","phi","nym","mia","atl"]
teamnamelist = ["washington-nationals","philadelphia-phillies","new-york-mets","miami-    marlins","atlanta-braves"]
teamlist = ["Washington Nationals","Philadelphia Phillies","New York Mets","Miami Marlins","Atlanta Braves"]

j=0
i=0
while (i<len(teamnamelist)) and (j<len(teamstate)):
    url = "http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/" + teamstate[j] + "/" +teamnamelist[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span class="stat">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the batting average of the",teamlist[i]," is: " ,price
    i+=1
    j+=1

text_file = open("statstest.txt", "a")
text_file.write("averages: {0}\n".format(price)) 
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Could you double check your indentation... it doesn't look like it survived the copy/paste

Comment: `i` and `j` always have exactly the same value, so you can get rid of one of them for starters.

Comment: Using a `for x, y, z in zip(teamstate, teamnamelist, teamlist)` seems prettier than a `while` approach.

Comment: Also, you have a lot more than just one element matching your regex.

Comment: as you can see, my skillset is really nonexistent.

Comment: While it's not my place to hijack your approach, are you open to using third-party libraries for this? :)

Comment: I could, but I am more confused as to why this code produces a multiple at the end.

Comment: You mean a list is produced at the end of every line, is that it? :)

Comment: probably. ha, that could be it.

Comment: See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Use `zip` on the lists. This pretty much combines them into one list composed of tuples with their elements matching up. Since you've got your elements ordered properly, this will work painlessly.
2. If you check the page, there are about 7 or 8 elements matching your regex. Using `re.findall` will already return a list, so some transformation is needed here if you want to properly get the batting average (second in the list).

Number 2 above is largely why your code is returning the following:

```
the batting average of the Washington Nationals  is:  ['22', '.304', '.362', '.530', '3.21', '2', '0.93', '.179']
the batting average of the Philadelphia Phillies  is:  ['19', '.306', '.364', '.468', '5.96', '2', '1.75', '.311']
the batting average of the New York Mets  is:  ['10', '.179', '.243', '.337', '6.75', '2', '1.64', '.304']
the batting average of the Miami Marlins  is:  ['27', '.301', '.358', '.451', '3.00', '2', '1.31', '.268']
the batting average of the Atlanta Braves  is:  ['6', '.179', '.225', '.337', '1.38', '3', '0.85', '.184']
[Finished in 19.0s]
```

Varying your approach a little:

```
import urllib
import re
##NL East stats.
teamstate = ["wsh","phi","nym","mia","atl"]
teamnamelist = ["washington-nationals","philadelphia-phillies","new-york-mets","miami-marlins","atlanta-braves"]
teamlist = ["Washington Nationals","Philadelphia Phillies","New York Mets","Miami Marlins","Atlanta Braves"]

for x, y, z in zip(teamstate, teamnamelist, teamlist):
    url = "http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/%s/%s" % (x, y)
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span class="stat">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    val = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)[1]
    print "The batting average of the %s is %s." % (z, str(val))
```

Result:

```
The batting average of the Washington Nationals is .304.
The batting average of the Philadelphia Phillies is .306.
The batting average of the New York Mets is .179.
The batting average of the Miami Marlins is .301.
The batting average of the Atlanta Braves is .179.
[Finished in 22.5s]
```

Using `lxml` and `requests` (because it's faster in the long run):

```
import requests as rq
from lxml import html

teamstate = ["wsh","phi","nym","mia","atl"]
teamnamelist = ["washington-nationals","philadelphia-phillies","new-york-mets","miami-marlins","atlanta-braves"]
teamlist = ["Washington Nationals","Philadelphia Phillies","New York Mets","Miami Marlins","Atlanta Braves"]

for x, y, z in zip(teamstate, teamnamelist, teamlist):
    url = "http://espn.go.com/mlb/team/_/name/%s/%s" % (x, y)
    r = rq.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
    val = tree.xpath("//span[@class='stat']/text()")[1]
    print "The batting average of the %s is %s." % (z, str(val))
```

Result:

```
The batting average of the Washington Nationals is .304.
The batting average of the Philadelphia Phillies is .306.
The batting average of the New York Mets is .179.
The batting average of the Miami Marlins is .301.
The batting average of the Atlanta Braves is .179.
[Finished in 10.6s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the green check icon near the top of my post if you found it helpful.